# 'Prefix not set' error installing Ubuntu x86_64

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, 64-bit

I'm trying to install Ubuntu instead of Fedora on my Lenovo V570 laptop and I'm having issues with the disk.

I downloaded the x86_64 version of the Ubuntu ISO from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download

I burned a CD from the ISO using Brasero and choosing 'burn image'.

When I re-boot from the CD I am notified that `prefix not set` and then it gives me the option to live boot, install, or check the disk for errors.

No matter which option I choose, the screen goes black. I can hear the disk spinning up but after a while it stops without showing me anything.

I'm at a loss, I though things were going well, any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

When I try using the same exact disk on my old, crappy HP desktop computer, it works fine!

Is there anything that I could be doing wrong when I install it? Do I need a different version?

Comment: How do you solve your problem?